# IONIC5 and ANGULAR 9 upgrade - error NG8001 <ion-header> is not a known element

Tags: angular9, ionic5

I followed the guide to upgrade to Ionic 5 (after solving all deprecated warnings) and also to Angular v9.

On the first build, I got a bunch of errors NG8001  is not a known element (for header, title, buttons, menu-button etc).

I searched the web and there was just one occurence of this error by a guy who placed a question on the same issue today!

Any idea how to solve?
Many thanks!

Comment: Which version you are upgrading from?

Comment: Version 4, upgraded to 4.11.10 (latest, I think), resolved all deprecation warnings and then upgraded to v5 + Angular 9. I found the issue, a file called "zone-flags.ts" should have been present (it's there on a new v5 project), but was not in the upgraded one. I copied it over a brand new v5 project, and all is well now... Dont know why it wasnt created by the upgrade.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue, a file called "zone-flags.ts" should have been present (it's there on a new v5 project), but was not in the upgraded one. I copied it over a brand new v5 project, and all is well now... Dont know why it wasnt created by the upgrade.

Thanks!